# How to approve PayPal subscription automatically without approval URL

Tags: reactjs, django, paypal, subscription

I am facing an issue with integrating PayPal subscriptions into my project.

**Currently, the integration process involves:**

1. adding PayPal as a payment method on my website using PayPal checkout.
2. Then, on the 'Plans & Pricing' page, I select a subscription plan, which creates a new PayPal subscription using the PayPal REST API in Backend.
3. From there, the API generates an approval URL, which redirects me to the PayPal Approval Page where I must input my PayPal credentials to approve the subscription.

**However, what I desire in my project is:**

the ability to subscribe to a plan without being redirected to the Approval Page and having to input my PayPal credentials again.

*Freelancer.com, for example, has this functionality where after verifying the payment method, there is no need to input PayPal credentials again when subscribing to a plan.
*

I would greatly appreciate any help in achieving this functionality.

Thank you,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Creating new PayPal transactions without payer approval requires a feature that's variously called reference transactions, vault, and future payments. Essentially the initial payer approval returns a token or billing agreement that is then kept on file in the payer's PayPal account (they can cancel it there), which so long as it remains active can be used to create new transactions from their account to the account they agreed to allow to bill them. For any amount, at any time. This can then be used from your own recurring billing engine.

(Unlike normal PayPal Subscriptions there will be no plan on PayPal's side, and PayPal will not bill anything automatically)

Using such an integration in the live environment requires that the receiving business account be approved for the "reference transactions" feature. The account's owner should contact PayPal's general support (not technical support) to request reference transactions, and explain the business need for it. (Another way is to apply for a [Braintree Gateway](https://www.braintreepayments.com/) account, which in addition to unbranded credit card processing includes the reference transactions feature for PayPal payments)

As for which PayPal API/integration to make use of the feature with once approved, [Save payment methods](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/save-payment-methods/) is the most recent one--at this time **available for US business accounts only**. If the receiver account is in a different country, after being approved for the reference transaction feature contact PayPal for guidance on what to integrate.